# banding photoshop auto-blend layers

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, hdr, panorama

I get some banding in Photoshop when I auto-blend (RAW) layers. Is there a way to overcome this?

Below is a cut-out from my panorama.

[image]

Comment: This is called posterization. Do you use 16 bit or 8 bit (if applicable) ?

Comment: Thanks! 16 bit indeed gave me a better (not totally perfect) result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

duplicate the image into two separate layers the first layer blur the layer until there isn't any banding; since there isn't any stars or objects in the sky. then drag that blured layer below the unedited layer. using the eraser tool use a softer brush and gradually erase bottom to top. that should help with fix the banding and also make the image look sharper.

Answer (score 1):

*@Pinhollow Euri* - I tried auto-blending in 16 bit, and I got a better result. So that will be the way to go in the future.

For now I will use the suggested fix by *Edward Benavides*, since I have worked for so long on the panorama to this point.

Answer (score 1):

I have occasionally understood the problem which you get. You have a slight variance of material at edges of photos and Photoshop is making hard transitions between exposures what results in posterisation.

There is a way of overcoming it but it seems to be non-automatable to me.

1. auto-merge without blending images together
2. for each layer

2.1 select the layer

2.2 ctrl+click thumbnail of layer

2.3 create pixel mask

2.4 select "feather" in "masks" tab big enough for you

IIRC, Photoshop creates a mask for each layer so you might only need to set feather for each layer. 2.3 and 2.4 can be recorded and assigned to a hotkey.

P.S. Your usage of term "blend" confused me. I hope that I understood you correctly now.